# Why we use (0,1,0) for free group proof in Banach-Tarski paradox

Tags: geometry

Why we use point $(0,1,0)$ as a starting point when we prove that rotations with $\theta = \arccos(\frac{1}{3})$ form free group? Why not $(\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}, \frac{\sqrt 2}{2}, 0)$ or any other not on one of the rotations axes?

> If $\rho: \mathbf{R}^3\to\mathbf{R}^3$ is an expression in $\mathcal G$ with length $n$ in reduced form, then $\rho(0,1,0)$ is of the following form, where $a,b, $ and $c$ are intergers:
>
> $$\rho(0,1,0) = \frac{1}{3^n}\left(a\sqrt 2, b, c\sqrt 2\right).$$

Comment: why not use (0,1,0)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having proven it for one point we know it is true for all the other points not on the axis because it is a rigid rotation.  We use $(0,1,0)$ because it makes the proof easy.  It is easy to multiply by $1$ and $0$.  It is similar to some statements "prove such and such about all triangles."  If the property is maintained by affine transformations you can prove it about one triangle and be done.  Often using a triangle like $(0,0),(1,0),(0,1)$ makes the calculations easier.

Comment: I think for this to be true we would need to be sure that we can get to *all the other points not on the axis* starting at $(0,1,0)$.

Comment: You know, I think that this is true not because all the points not on the axes are equivalent in this sense, but because that is our setup. We start with $(0,1,0)$ and two axes $x$ and $z$. So coordinate system is per Caley graph.

Comment: No, starting at $(0,1,0)$ you can only get to its orbit. which for a free group on two generators is only countably many points.  The important thing to the proof is that no word applied to $(0,1,0)$ except the empty word brings us back to $(0,1,0)$.  Using this starting point makes that easier.